# Neural Network for a Robot

Tags: neural-network, robotics

I need to implement a Robot Brain, I used feedforward neural network as a Controller. The robot has 24 sonar sonsor, and only one ouput which is R=Right, L=Left, F=Forward, B=Back. I also have a large dataset which contain sonar data and the desired output. The FNN is trained using backpropagation algorithm.

I used neuroph Studio to construct the FNN and to do the trainnig. Here the network params:

Input layer: 24
Hidden Layer: 10
Output Layer: 1
LearnningRate: 0.5
Momentum: 0.7
GlobalError: 0.1

My problem is that during iteration the error drop slightly and seems to be static. I tried to change the parameter but I'm not getting any useful result!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 1 of n encoding for the output. Use 4 output neurons, and set up your target (output) data like this:

```
1 0 0 0 = right
0 1 0 0 = left
0 0 1 0 = forward
0 0 0 1 = back
```

Reduce the number of input sensors (and corresponding input neurons) to begin with, down to 3 or 5. This will simplify things so you can understand what's going on. Later you can build back up to 24 inputs.

Neural networks often get stuck in local minima during training, that could be why your error is static. Increasing the momentum can help avoid this.

Your learning rate looks quite high. Try 0.1, but play around with these values. Every problem is different and there are no values guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you Andrelucas for your help, I did what you said (change the output to four instead of one, hidden=15, input=24 learning rate=0.1, momentum=0.7) The MSE droped dramaticly, it's now fluctating between 0.5 and 0.4, instead of being stauck at 2.5. I will try to change the params in order to minimize the MSE (<0.1) and I will post the result. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Hi again, After days of trying, I can't get the MSE drops to 0.01 (it only reachs 0.03), I use Neuroph studio for my simulation, I'v tride all the combination of the (changing the size of hidden layers, learning rate, momentum) Please if you have any suggestions, I will apreciate it.

Comment: 0.03 _could_ be fine. 0.01 is just a suggestion. Are you using a validation set to determine when to exit training?